# Yii реляционая связь

Tags: фреймворк, php, yii

Здравствуйте, запутался в реляционных связях YII, прошу помощи.

Есть 2 таблицы, Товары и Сопутствующие

Products(id, title, etc..), и related(products_id, link_id)

Не могу связать их так, что бы в товаре вывести все Сопутствующие товары.

Читал доку, пробовал сам, ничего не получилось.

Нашел в доке, может кому понадобиться

```
   'p_related'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Related','products_id','joinType'=>'INNER JOIN'),
   'related'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Products',array('link_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'p_related','joinType'=>'INNER JOIN'),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Products{
//
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
    //related - это ваше имя. HAS_MANY - предопределенная константа related_id - поле РОДИТЕЛЬСКОГО товара
            'related' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Products', 'related_id'),
        );
    }
//
```

Comment: Мне кажется или с вашей связью можно вывести всего 1 сопутствующий товар? т.к. в товаре всего 1 поле related_id, а моем случаи отдельная таблица которая связывает товары и Сопутствующие товары.

Answer (score 0):

Products->**with('relationName')**->find вызывали? Покажите вообще как связаны модели, как вы их вызываете и ищете

Comment: Я не знаю какую в этом случаи делать связь, но я знаю как бы я поступил на CI :)

Comment: Я бы сделал метод в модели Products:  
    
getRelatedProducts($id_product)
{
   return Related::model()->findAll('id=:id',array(':id'=>$id_product));
}  
  
Получил Products, вызвал: Products::model()->getRelatedProducts($product->id);